# Standard normal moments

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, moments

My textbook says, without proof, that $E(X^4)=3$, where $X\sim N(0,1)$. Is it so simple to obtain?

Comment: Simple is a subjective word. It is fairly a standard result that all odd moments of a standard normal are zero, and an even moment is the product of all odd numbers below it. For example, $E(X^4)=3\times 1$, and $E(X^6)=5\times 3\times 1$.

Answer (score 0):

If you start with the moment generating function $M_{X}(t)$, one can quickly obtain arbitrary moments. The moment generating function for a standard normal distribution is given by
$$
\begin{aligned}
M_{X}(t) &= \operatorname E[\exp(tX)]\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dX \exp(tX)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}X^2\right)\\
&= \exp\left(\frac{1}{2}t^2\right),
\end{aligned}
$$
where I quoted the answer from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Examples), but this can also be easily calculated by completing the square.

Because
$$
\exp(tX) = 1 + t\,X + \frac{t^2\,X^2}{2!} + \frac{t^3\,X^3}{3!} + \cdots +\frac{t^n\,X^n}{n!} + \cdots, 
$$
subsequently,
$$
M_X(t) =  1 + t \operatorname E (X) + \frac{t^2 \operatorname E (X^2)}{2!} + \frac{t^3\operatorname E (X^3)}{3!}+\cdots + \frac{t^n\operatorname E (X^n)}{n!}+\cdots.
$$
Therefore by differentiating the moment generating function, you can obtain the desired moment. In particular, the fourth moment $\operatorname E[X^4]$ is given by
$$
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname E[X^4] &= \frac{d^4}{dt^4}M_{X}(t) \bigg\vert_{t=0}\\
&= \frac{d^4}{dt^4}\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}t^2\right) \bigg\vert_{t=0}\\
&= \exp\left(\frac{1}{2}t^2\right) (t^4 + 6 t^2 + 3) \bigg\vert_{t=0}\\
&= 3.
\end{aligned}
$$